# How do I use python interface of Stanford NER(named entity recogniser)?

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I want to use Stanford NER in python using pyner library. Here is one basic code snippet.

```
import ner 
tagger = ner.HttpNER(host='localhost', port=80)
tagger.get_entities("University of California is located in California, United States")
```

When I run this on my local python console(IDLE). It should have given me an output like this

```
  {'LOCATION': ['California', 'United States'],
 'ORGANIZATION': ['University of California']}
```

but when I execut this, it showed empty brackets. I am actually new to all this.

Comment: What method are you using to run the stanford-ner server as an http server? I can successfully run it as a socket server and use the pyner client with tagger = ner.SocketNER(host='localhost', port=8080) and get the answer you are looking to receive.

Comment: Can you post ur code? ... I want NER's output on my IDLE console @Ryan O'Neill

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I am able to run the stanford-ner server in socket mode using:

```
java -mx1000m -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer \
    -loadClassifier classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz \
    -port 8080 -outputFormat inlineXML
```

and receive the following output from the command line:

```
Loading classifier from 
/Users/roneill/stanford-ner-2012-11-11/classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz 
... done [1.7 sec].
```

Then in python repl:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ner
>>> tagger = ner.SocketNER(host='localhost', port=8080)
>>> tagger.get_entities("University of California is located in California, United States")
{'ORGANIZATION': ['University of California'], 'LOCATION': ['California', 'United States']}
```

Comment: What did u download before all this? ... how to start the server exactly?... I have downloaded Stanford Named Entity Recognizer version 1.2.7 as of now?

Comment: I download the zip file located on the [Stanford Named Entity Recognizer (NER)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) website. The one that says [Download Stanford Named Entity Recognizer version 1.2.7](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-ner-2012-11-11.zip)

Comment: Bingo ... Thanks man... there was a problem with basic understanding

Comment: and What if I want NER to recognize a different type than 'ORGANISATION','LOCATION' .....

Comment: I recommend asking a separate question and providing an example of what you are looking to receive as an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746695/how-do-i-include-more-than-one-classifiers-when-using-stanford-named-entity-reco

Comment: For me, the problem was not including `-outputFormat inlineXML` (which I do not see anywhere in the pyner README example). Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Getting error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory". Downloaded sl4j.zip but not sure where to include it.