# Combine CRFClassifier and RegexNERSequenceClassifier model outputs - Stanford Core NLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I've serialized a CRF Model using [CRFClassifier](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/crf/CRFClassifier.html) based on a custom dataset.
I can access to the model using the below code.

```
CRFClassifier<CoreLabel> crfClassifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions("crf_ner_model.ser.gz");
```

I also have a set of Regex Mappings (*Java Regular expressions and corresponding labels*) using which I instantiate an instance of [RegexNERSequenceClassifier](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/regexp/RegexNERSequenceClassifier.html)

```
RegexNERSequenceClassifier regexNERSequenceClassifier = new RegexNERSequenceClassifier(mappingPath, true, true, null);
```

I am able to individually call the `classify()` for both of these classifiers and they successfully annotate the test data-set.
Example:

```
List<CoreLabel> testData = new ArrayList<CoreLabel>();
// assume testData is initialized with values.

List<CoreLabel> crfOutput = crfClassifier.classify(testData);
List<CoreLabel> regexOutput = regexNERSequenceClassifier.classify(testData);
```

Sample Output using above code:

> **Input Test Data**: 72" x 60" wooden bed
>
> **crfOutput**: `72" (label: O)`, `x (label: O)`, `60" (label: O)`, `wooden (label: material)`, `bed (label: category)`
>
> `(label: O)` *is the background symbol*
>
> **regexOutput**: `72" (label: UNIT_OF_LENGTH)`, `x`, `60" (label: UNIT_OF_LENGTH)`, `wooden`, `bed`

However when I try to combine them, such that a test document is first classified by CRF and then by RegexNER, it doesn't work (*RegexNER doesn't tag anything even though there are tokens matching the regex, only the CRF tags are visible*).
Example:

```
List<CoreLabel> crfOutput = crfClassifier.classify(testData);
// send crfOutput as input to RegexNER
List<CoreLabel> regexOutput = regexNERSequenceClassifier.classify(crfOutput);
```

How do I combine the two classifiers. I tried using NERClassifierCombiner.java (as described here: [Stanford NER: Can I use two classifiers at once in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257554/stanford-ner-can-i-use-two-classifiers-at-once-in-my-code/27368251#27368251)) but that doesn't work either.

Comment: See this: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/983

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without using the StanfordCoreNLP Pipeline?

Comment: Python (CoreNLP)? https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanfordnlp/issues/184  Otherwise, regex (`sed` ...).