# Pyner empty dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pos-tagger, empty-list

I am using the python interface of [Stanford Named Entity Recognizer (NER)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml). The code can be found at [Pyner Code](https://github.com/dat/pyner)

```
import ner


if __name__ == "__main__": 
  tagger = ner.HttpNER(host='localhost', port=8080)
  print tagger.get_entities("University of California is located in California, United States")
  print tagger.json_entities("Alice went to the Museum of Natural History.")
```

---

The supposed outputs:

```
{'LOCATION': ['California', 'United States'], 'ORGANIZATION': ['University of California']}
```

---

```
'{"ORGANIZATION": ["Museum of Natural History"], "PERSON": ["Alice"]}'
```

---

**Problem:** I am getting empty sets why?

---

I tried the following [solution-StackoverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722802/how-do-i-use-python-interface-of-stanford-nernamed-entity-recogniser) but it didn't work I received the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer.<init>(NERServer.java:71)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer.main(NERServer.java:331)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Run the stanford-ner server in socket mode using:

java -mx256m -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer \
    -loadClassifier classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz \
    -port 8081 -outputFormat inlineXML.

Save the code in a windows batch file and run it in command prompt.

There is a problem with your port 8080. That's why I have changed the port to 8081. After the server gets running type your python code-

```
>>>import ner
>>>tagger = ner.SocketNER(host='localhost', port=8081)
>>>tagger.get_entities("University of California is located in California, United States")
```